# Thousand-separation vanishes after VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA macro that reads value of A1 and adds text to C1 which already has numbers. The problem is the moment text is added to C1, comma vanishes from the figure and **1,234.56** becomes 123456. Is there a way to get around this issue?

```
Sub WhatA1()
    If Range("A1").Value = "Daily Wages" Then
    [C1].Value = "Total: " & [C1].Value
    Else: [C1].Value = "Orders: " & [C1].Value
  End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub WhatA1()
If Range("A1").Value = "Daily Wages" Then
    [C1].Formula = "Total: " & format([C1].Value,"#,###.##")
Else
    [C1].Formula = "Orders: " & format([C1].Value,"#,###.##")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PNuts, copy and pasted from something I did this morning and forgot to modify :). Original code edited

Comment: FYI, Another alternative would have been to take the .text instead of the .value and it should give you the formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

An alternatives that would leave the underlying value available for future calculations would be a custom number format.

```
Sub WhatA1()
    If Range("A1").Value = "Daily Wages" Then
        [C1].NumberFormat = "Tot\al\: #,##0.00"
    Else
        [C1].NumberFormat = "O\r\d\e\r\s\: #,##0.00"
    End If
End Sub
```

This provides the cell labelling you are looking for while retaining the cell's numerical value. Like other number formats, the cell must be wide enough to display the whole formatted result ot it will show ######.

Comment: Thanx Jeeped, your solution also works great, except one issue. If I try to change the text in the cell from Total to DFM and Orders to ADX for a different task, I get error setting .NumberFormat.

Comment: @MunirAbrar - There are reserved letters used to represent different elements in a format mask; e.g m for minute or month. Wrap the text in quotes like "Total to DFM "#,##0.00 or precede each letter with a backslash like \T\o\t\a\l \t\o \D\F\M #,##0.00.In VBA. I prefer the latter so I don't have to deal with quotes inside a quoted string. Excel will only keep the backslash escape characters that it needs. Recording your action is a quick way to get it right.

Comment: Thanx Jeeped, you explained it very well.